# Laravel foreach loop with checkboxes

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I have below two arrays

```
$vendor_permissions = [1,2,3,4]
$assigned_vendor_permissions = [1,3]
```

I have a table with checkboxes for all permissions in one row.

Now, I want to check only those checkbox which has `$assigned_vendor_permissions`, means, in this case, there are 4 checkboxes as per `$vendor_permissions` and 2 must be checked as permissions `$assigned_vendor_permissions [1,3]` assigned to the user.

I tried with the below loop, but I could not get success, as it repeats checkboxes
more than 4 times,

```
@foreach ( $vendor_permissions as $vendor_permission )             
    @if ($assigned_vendor_permissions->isNotEmpty())
        @foreach ( $assigned_vendor_permissions as $rolem )                                        
            <td style="width: 15%"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" id="{{ $vendor_permission->name }}" 
            {{ $vendor_permission->id == $rolem->id ? 'checked="checked"' : '' }} value="{{ $vendor_permission->id }}""><span></span></label></td> 
        @endforeach   
    @else
        <td style="width: 15%"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" id="{{ $vendor_permission->name }}" 
            value="{{ $vendor_permission->id }}""><span></span></label></td> 
    @endif                          
@endforeach
```

How can I get these checkboxes checked and unchecked based on the array?

Output of `dd($assigned_vendor_permissions);`

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:6 [▶
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "vendor_create"
    "guard_name" => "web"
    "created_at" => null
    "updated_at" => null
    "pivot" => array:2 [▶
      "role_id" => 2
      "permission_id" => 1
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:6 [▶
    "id" => 2
    "name" => "vendor_read"
    "guard_name" => "web"
    "created_at" => null
    "updated_at" => null
    "pivot" => array:2 [▶
      "role_id" => 2
      "permission_id" => 2
    ]
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of loop,Use in_array

```
@foreach ( $vendor_permissions as $vendor_permission )

    <td style="width: 15%">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" 
                   id="{{ $vendor_permission->name }}"
                   value="{{ $vendor_permission->id }}"  
                {{(is_array($assigned_vendor_permissions)&&in_array($vendor_permission->id,$assigned_vendor_permissions))?"checked":null}}
            >
            <span>
                
            </span>
        </label>
    </td>

@endforeach
```

Comment: How to use this for laravel collection if there are collections instead of an array for assigned permissions?

Comment: just return toArray()

Comment: now it shows all 4 checkboxes but doesn't have a checkbox checked with 3 permissions. All are unchecked.

Comment: first check dd($assigned_vendor_permissions) and show what you have

Comment: @rjcode which id do you want to check .is it  "id" => 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234764/discussion-between-john-lobo-and-rjcode).